# Assignment gives error: "already defined"

Tags: pine-script

I'm pretty new into Pine Script.
I'm facing an error not so clear to understand for me.
I need to define and use a variable having the function of a counter. Here is the script:

```
var CountOverB = 0

CountOverB= if OverB==true and OverB[1]==false
    CountOverB=1
else 
    CountOverB=CountOverB+1
```

the error is "'CountOverB' is already defined."

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello Sandrino, Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are satisfied with the answer, please set the checkmark. This will give me some extra points. If not, please explain why not.

Answer (score 2):

To assign a value to an already declared variable, use operator `:=`, not `=`.

```
var CountOverB = 0

if OverB==true and OverB[1]==false
    CountOverB := 1
else 
    CountOverB := CountOverB+1
```